# Dell laptop with DisplayPort (but NOT mini) to Thunderbolt monitor

Tags: displayport, thunderbolt-display

I have a DELL E6410, with [DisplayPort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort) output. How can I connect it to an Apple monitor with a Thunderbolt input? Searching for that kind of adapter keeps returning *mini DisplayPort* ones, which won't help.

Going through DVI or HDMI perhaps?

Comment: jschmidt's answer below is correct, you cannot connect it directly and there are currently no adapters available.

Comment: @DaveNelson: how about DVI laptop to Thunderbolt monitor?

Comment: Thunderbolt combines Display Port and PCIe, Apple's Thunderbolt displays require both Display Port for video and PCIe for data. If you look at a Cinema Display that uses Display Port you will see that it includes a USB connector that has to be plugged in for the computer can control the monitor. The Thunderbolt display is designed in such a way that it requires the PCIe connection where the Cinema Display does not require the USB. As jschmidt states below, the Apple Thunderbolt monitor requires a Mac with Thunderbolt... for now at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Apple's [spec page](http://www.apple.com/displays/specs.html), the Thunderbolt Display requires a Thunderbolt-equipped Mac. So, I don't think there is any way to get it to work. Although Thunderbolt allows for video steams and you can connect a DisplayPort monitor to a Thunderbolt port, the reverse is not true.

If you can get your hands on the older Apple Cinema Display with a mini-DisplayPort, that should work with something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003N3DTKY).